# What is the solution of "XML Parsing Error" in Mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: angular, http, firefox

**Issue is:**

Whenever i open site in `Mozilla Firefox` browser which is calling some `http request` then it's show error in console `XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location` and `XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location`.

[image: web service calls to get xml]

**My code is:**

```
getAsync (url: string) {
  let localStorageKeys = ConsoleConstants.LOCAL_STORAGE_KEYS;
  let consoleUser = 
  this._tokenManagerService.retrieve(localStorageKeys.CONSOLE_USER);

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('x-sk', consoleUser[localStorageKeys.LOGIN_KEY]);

  return this._http
  .get(url, { headers : headers})
  .map((resp: Response) => resp.json())
  .catch(this._utilsService.handleError);}
```

Comment: Is it common to just that Browser? What does Chrome give for example?

Comment: Do you have the normal header part <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Try opening the file in some software like Wordpad/TextEdit etc.

Comment: This is not a file. It's a angular 2 `http call request` and this http request can be return data in a `json format` or any other format so when i open website in `Firefox` browser then it's show this console error on all http request but chrome and all other browser not show any console error.

Comment: So try something like this then
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/top.xml

Comment: can you please provide the solution to where and how to insert above mentioned detail in my code.

Please find my code above i have updated my question.

Comment: You don't insert into code. You run it from Terminal of Mac. Then you can see the results of the payload. You can then work out if the header part was there for example that I mentioned. If that is there you can work out why the xml is malformed. You can at least paste it then. If you're on Windows, checkout gitbash and install curl in that.

Comment: Can you please let me know whether the **XML parse** error is because there some problem in the way the **http request** is hit to the server or the service is hit correctly and the response from the server does not have appropriate response header

Comment: How am I supposed to check your localhost! You need to inspect xml payload returned using URLs in your screenshot

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused by an empty Ok response from my web api. I fixed it by putting something useful in the Ok constructor. I guess this is because of the resp.json() which doesn't find any data.